# PHP foreach not getting last values of array

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a script where I need to separate months by (Monday to Thursday) and (Friday to Sunday).

I am using a function to create an array of all dates in a range and then loop through that array to separate the days.

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo){
    $aryRange=array();

    $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

    if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
    {
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
            array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
}

$date = "2013-07-01";
$end_date = "2013-07-31";
$date_range = createDateRangeArray($date, $end_date);

$final_array = array();
$temp_array = array();

foreach ($date_range as $value) {
    $temp_array[] = $value;
    $day_of_week = date("N", strtotime($value));

    if ($day_of_week == 4 || $day_of_week == 7) {
        $final_array[] = $temp_array;
        $temp_array = array();
    }

}
```

When I do a print_r($date_range) I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-07-01
    [1] => 2013-07-02
    [2] => 2013-07-03
    [3] => 2013-07-04
    [4] => 2013-07-05
    [5] => 2013-07-06
    [6] => 2013-07-07
    [7] => 2013-07-08
    [8] => 2013-07-09
    [9] => 2013-07-10
    [10] => 2013-07-11
    [11] => 2013-07-12
    [12] => 2013-07-13
    [13] => 2013-07-14
    [14] => 2013-07-15
    [15] => 2013-07-16
    [16] => 2013-07-17
    [17] => 2013-07-18
    [18] => 2013-07-19
    [19] => 2013-07-20
    [20] => 2013-07-21
    [21] => 2013-07-22
    [22] => 2013-07-23
    [23] => 2013-07-24
    [24] => 2013-07-25
    [25] => 2013-07-26
    [26] => 2013-07-27
    [27] => 2013-07-28
    [28] => 2013-07-29
    [29] => 2013-07-30
    [30] => 2013-07-31
)
```

However when I run it through the foreach loop above it is grabbing everything except the last couple days of the month.  If I run a print_r($final_array) I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07-01
            [1] => 2013-07-02
            [2] => 2013-07-03
            [3] => 2013-07-04
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07-05
            [1] => 2013-07-06
            [2] => 2013-07-07
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07-08
            [1] => 2013-07-09
            [2] => 2013-07-10
            [3] => 2013-07-11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07-12
            [1] => 2013-07-13
            [2] => 2013-07-14
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07-15
            [1] => 2013-07-16
            [2] => 2013-07-17
            [3] => 2013-07-18
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07-19
            [1] => 2013-07-20
            [2] => 2013-07-21
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07-22
            [1] => 2013-07-23
            [2] => 2013-07-24
            [3] => 2013-07-25
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-07-26
            [1] => 2013-07-27
            [2] => 2013-07-28
        )

)
```

What is even weirder is that when I change the date range to (2013-06-01 to 2013-06-30) or (2013-08-01 to 2013-08-31) it spits all the dates into $final_array the way that it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought process is you're missing the final step of adding `$temp_array` back in, because you aren't quite getting to the the `4` or `7` mark. It works with other dates because the day of week sets up nicely.

Try confirming by adding the array (if not empty) after the foreach:

```
foreach ($date_range as $value) {
    $temp_array[] = $value;
    $day_of_week = date("N", strtotime($value));

    if ($day_of_week == 4 || $day_of_week == 7) {
        $final_array[] = $temp_array;
        $temp_array = array();
    }

}

if ( count( $temp_array ) > 0 ){ // anything leftover?
    $final_array[] = $temp_array; // append to $final_array
}
```

Comment: Haha I do not know how I missed that.  It worked perfectly. I will mark this the accepted answer as soon as it will let me.

Comment: Sometimes just takes another pair of eyes ;) Happy to help!